# SQL looping and Incrementing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, loops

I'm using SQL server 2008

I have the following SQL getting all dates between today and December 31st 2012. What I now what to do is start with a value of 10000 and increment this value equally so on December 31st I have a value of 150000.

```
Declare @projection table(d datetime, t decimal)
Declare @d datetime
Declare @t decimal(18, 2)

set @d='20110527'
set @t=100000

While @d<='20121231'
Begin
Insert into @projection values (@d, @t)
set @d=@d+1
End
Select d as DateCol, t as TotalRevenue from @projection
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This linearly interpolates `t` from 10000 to 150000.

```
Declare @projection table(d datetime, t decimal)
Declare @d datetime, @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime
Declare @t decimal(18,4), @t1 decimal(18, 4), @t2 decimal(18,4), @tincr decimal(18,4)

set @d1='20110527'
set @d2='20121231'
set @t1=10000
set @t2=150000

Set @tincr = (@t2-@t1)/DATEDIFF(D, @d1, @d2)

Set @d = @d1
set @t = @t1

While @d<=@d2
Begin
Insert into @projection values (@d, @t)
set @d=@d+1
Set @t=@t+@tincr
End
Select d as DateCol, t as TotalRevenue from @projection
```

Note that I cranked up the decimal precision to 4 to make rounding errors insignificant.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the quick response. My final value though is now 150002. But it must be 150000.

Comment: Change `decimal(18,2)` to `decimal(18,4)` to eliminate the rounding error.